# P(A given -B) if you have P(A given B)

Tags: math, statistics

Is there a formula for calculating this in general. It seems like there would be a connection of some type.
I know P(A|B) and need to calculate P(A|B') where B' equals "not B".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability / [math.se], not programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

P(A|B) = P(AB)/P(B)   WHERE P(AB) = P( A INTERSECT B )

Wouldn't P(A| NOT B) be =  P(A INTERSECT WITH NOT B)/ P(NOT B)

Just replace B with B complement in the formula. And if you know P(B), you know P(B complement)

Comment: Also this probably belongs in math.stackexchange